# Как работать с табличными и строчными подзапросами с помощью IN,ANY,ALL в sql?

Tags: mysql, sql

Привет.

Вопрос по `sql` по теме "Подзапросы". Есть скалярный подзапрос - он возвращает одно значение. Скалярный подзапрос можно поставить, например, справа от оператора =. То есть, скалярный запрос возвращает одну строку и показывает один столбец в строке - в руках у меня ячейка, из которой можно вытащить ЗНАЧЕНИЕ (например, число) и это значение поставить справа от знака равно. К скалярному подзапросу нет пока вопросов. Со скалярными запросами применяются операторы <,>,<=...

Запрос также может вернуть ТАБЛИЦУ или СТРОКУ. Это нескалярный запрос. Пишут, что для работы с такими нескалярными запросами есть операторы `IN,ANY,ALL`.. **Мне не понятно, как можно, например, запрос, который несколько строк возвращает запихать в тот же IN - получается ..IN(а тут таблица)**.

В `IN` можно передать несколько значений через запятую (...`IN(1,3,5);` - этот вариант использования мне понятен). Например, это

```
...WHERE id IN(1,3,5);
```

Можно переписать так:

```
...WHERE id=1 OR id=3 OR id=5;
```

Comment: вот если ваш подзапрос вернет 3 строки состоящие из одной колонки со значениями 1, 3 и 5 - то получится аналогично IN(1,3,5)

Comment: Mike, насколько я понял, операторам IN,ANY,ALL можно "кидать" только таблицу-столбец. эти операторы этот столбец как бы разбирают на ячейки-данные и записывают через запятую. я правильно понимаю?

Comment: Почти правильно. потому что вы не знакомы с многостолбцовым IN. например `(x,y) IN( (1,2), (3,4) )` аналогично `(x=1 and y=2) OR (x=3 and y=4)` для такого варианта подзапрос должен вернуть таблицу из двух колонок

Comment: Операторы IN, ANY и неуказанный Вами SOME полностью эквивалентны (разница только в синтаксисе) - им достаточно, чтобы хотя бы одна запись из набора, который вернул подзапрос, совпадала с записью из таблиц(ы) основного запроса. А вот оператору ALL этого мало - ему надо, чтобы совпадали ВСЕ возвращённые подзапросом записи, т.е. он проверяет не что "есть равное", а что "нет не-равных".

Comment: PS. (почти оффтоп  по мотивам _Запрос также может вернуть ТАБЛИЦУ или СТРОКУ._) Запрос ВСЕГДА возвращает набор записей. Другое дело, что этот набор может содержать ни одной, одну или более одной записи, а структура записи содержать одно поле или более одного. Под слово "скалярный" подходит запрос, в структуре возврата которого строго 1 поле, и возвращается 0 или 1 запись. Под слово "строка" подходит запрос, который возвращает 0 или 1 запись (включая и те, что скалярные). Ну а слово "таблица" накрывает любые варианты.